# GitLab Disastry Recovery DB read-only issue

Tags: gitlab, disaster-recovery

We are setting up GitLab - DR, we have replicated secondary slave from primary Postgres database.

But we are getting READ ONLY issues since DB slave is in read only mode, we can't make DB- READ WRITE since it's secondary.

What should be the standard way to proceed with DR setup for GitLab?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are setting up for GitLab DR: [Geo is the official solution since Nov. 2017 (GitLab 10.4)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2017/11/22/gitlab-10-2-released/#gitlab-geo-is-now-generally-available)

If you are using **[Geo](https://about.gitlab.com/solutions/geo/)** (premium or ultimate GitLab instance only), then [the documentation](http://gitlab.lcqb.upmc.fr/help/administration/geo/replication/database.md) would suggest:

> The GitLab primary node where the write operations happen will connect to the primary database server, and the secondary nodes which are read-only will connect to the secondary database servers (which are also read-only).
>
> Note:
> In database documentation, you may see "`primary`" being referenced as "`master`"
> and "`secondary`" as either "`slave`" or "`standby`" server (read-only).
>
> We recommend using **[PostgreSQL replication slots](https://medium.com/@tk512/replication-slots-in-postgresql-b4b03d277c75)** to ensure that the primary retains all the data necessary for the secondaries to recover.

So make sure those [replication slots](https://medium.com/@tk512/replication-slots-in-postgresql-b4b03d277c75) are properly configured.